# How to concat PHP vars for use in menu

Tags: php, html, string-concatenation, concatenation

I'm not a PHP guy, however I believe PHP can be used to accomplish this.

Basically I'm using the same absolute path in my main menu + /about, /blog etc so figured well my files are already PHP why not use a Var to do this :) (I come from a Flash AS background)

Testing link: http://s433108212.onlinehome.us/

This is what I've tried below, but to no avail :(

```
<div id="nav_bar">

<?php $athenasweburl = 'http://s433108212.onlinehome.us/'; ?>

<ul class="nav">
    <li class="<?php echo $page === 'home' ? "selected" : "" ?>"><a href="<?php $athenasweburl; ?>">Home</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo $page === 'about' ? "selected" : "" ?>"><a href="<?php echo ($athenasweburl+'about'); ?>">About</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo $page === 'blog' ? "selected" : "" ?>"><a href="<?php $athenasweburl+'blog'; ?>">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo $page === 'book' ? "selected" : "" ?>"><a href="<?php $athenasweburl+'book'; ?>">Book</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo $page === 'events' ? "selected" : "" ?>"><a href="<?php $athenasweburl+'events'; ?>">Events</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo $page === 'services' ? "selected" : "" ?>"><a href="<?php $athenasweburl+'services'; ?>">Services</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo $page === 'contact' ? "selected" : "" ?>"><a href="#dialog" name="modal">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="search"><input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search') { this.value = ''; }" value="Search" /></li>
    <li class="search_btn"><a href="#" title="Lets find it!"><div class="search_go">Go</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

thoughts anyone?

Comment: This isn't very relevant to the question, but I just wanted to say I like the design leon :)

Comment: rather inefficient, my approach would be an array of sections names, and a loop.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just do it in a foreach? and loop through a array of "navigation" items? also just do `href="/mymenu/"` (is more than efficient, the `/` makes it an absolute path).

Comment: Thx @Killrawr and wow tons of solutions! Thanks everyone! I'll get back here after I try em...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP + adds numbers together.. What you looking for is gluing strings.. Replace the + signs with . (dot), and an echo in front of each string, and it should work.

```
<div id="nav_bar">

<?php
$menu = array("home","about","blog","book","events","services");
function echoListItem($item){
    global $page;
    $url = 'http://s433108212.onlinehome.us/';
    if($item != "home") $url .= $item;
    $selected = $item == $page ? 'selected' : '';
    echo '<li class="'.$selected.'"><a href="'.$url.'">'.ucfirst($item).'</a></li>';
}
?>

<ul class="nav">
    <?php array_walk($menu, 'echoListItem'); ?>
    <li class="<?php echo $page === "contact" ? "selected" : "" ?>"><a href="#dialog" name="modal">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="search"><input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search') { this.value = ''; }" value="Search" /></li>
    <li class="search_btn"><a href="#" title="Lets find it!"><div class="search_go">Go</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

This should do just about the same!

Comment: WOOT THANKS! :D That saves so many lines, and is just dynamically sexy!

Comment: No problem, my friend :) Happy I could help. About the dot vs plus thing. Javascript, Actionscript and lots of other languages: `"Concat "+"these"`. In PHP: `"Concat "."these"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't output the URL. Note the addition of `echo` in the second stanza.

```
<li class="<?php echo $page === 'home' ? "selected" : "" ?>"><a href="<?php echo $athenasweburl; ?>">Home</a></li>
```

And concatenation uses `.`, not `+`.

```
<li class="<?php echo $page === 'about' ? "selected" : "" ?>"><a href="<?php echo $athenasweburl . 'about'; ?>">About</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP uses a dot notation "." To concatenate variables and strings etc. To concatenate the string "blog" to $athenasweburl, you would use

```
  $athenasweburl = $athenasweburl."blog/";
  echo $athenasweburl; //http://s433108212.onlinehome.us/blog/
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How would you put that into the li's? I'm trying this out now

Comment: Leon, I would use the function Esben provided, however if you wanted to use a similar concatenate someplace else, here is a short hand technique:

Comment: Sorry ran out of time, here is the code: <a href="<?php echo $athenasweburl=$athenasweburl."blog/"; ?>" target="_blank">Blog</a> . Because PHP will go through and resolve  variables first, $athenasweburl will be re assigned with the string blog/ appended to the root before it is echo'ed out.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit a similar issue not that long ago.

Assuming you have $page defined somewhere else as well...

```
<div id="nav_bar">

<?php $athenasweburl = 'http://s433108212.onlinehome.us/'; ?>

<ul class="nav">
    <li class="<?php echo ($page === "home" ? "selected" : "") ?>"><a href="<?php $athenasweburl; ?>">Home</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($page === "about" ? "selected" : "") ?>"><a href="<?php echo ($athenasweburl+'about'); ?>">About</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($page === "blog" ? "selected" : "") ?>"><a href="<?php $athenasweburl.'blog'; ?>">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($page === "book" ? "selected" : "") ?>"><a href="<?php $athenasweburl.'book'; ?>">Book</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($page === "events" ? "selected" : "") ?>"><a href="<?php $athenasweburl.'events'; ?>">Events</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($page === "services" ? "selected" : "") ?>"><a href="<?php $athenasweburl.'services'; ?>">Services</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo $page === "contact" ? "selected" : "") ?>"><a href="#dialog" name="modal">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="search"><input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search') { this.value = ''; }" value="Search" /></li>
    <li class="search_btn"><a href="#" title="Lets find it!"><div class="search_go">Go</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I do! Here php $page = 'home'; include("includes/athenas_header.php");  that's going on every page and it pulls in the header file which contains the nav, trying out your solution now!